# How to send from JQuery to SQL database?

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter

I'm using this nice lib to grab the tweets from twitter ...

But I'm really stuck with this problem,

I want to send some tweet data (say screen_name and tweet_id) to an SQL database, but I really don't know where to initiate the process and connect to db (via the php file)

which function and which like you suggest to start the call ? and what to write to call the php file?

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.tweet = function(o){
    var s = $.extend({
      username: null,                           // [string or array] required unless using the 'query' option; one or more twitter screen names
      list: null,                               // [string]   optional name of list belonging to username
      favorites: false,                         // [boolean]  display the user's favorites instead of his tweets
      query: null,                              // [string]   optional search query
      avatar_size: null,                        // [integer]  height and width of avatar if displayed (48px max)
      count: 3,                                 // [integer]  how many tweets to display?
      fetch: null,                              // [integer]  how many tweets to fetch via the API (set this higher than 'count' if using the 'filter' option)
      page: 1,                                  // [integer]  which page of results to fetch (if count != fetch, you'll get unexpected results)
      retweets: true,                           // [boolean]  whether to fetch (official) retweets (not supported in all display modes)
      intro_text: null,                         // [string]   do you want text BEFORE your your tweets?
      outro_text: null,                         // [string]   do you want text AFTER your tweets?
      join_text:  null,                         // [string]   optional text in between date and tweet, try setting to "auto"
      auto_join_text_default: "i said,",        // [string]   auto text for non verb: "i said" bullocks
      auto_join_text_ed: "i",                   // [string]   auto text for past tense: "i" surfed
      auto_join_text_ing: "i am",               // [string]   auto tense for present tense: "i was" surfing
      auto_join_text_reply: "i replied to",     // [string]   auto tense for replies: "i replied to" @someone "with"
      auto_join_text_url: "i was looking at",   // [string]   auto tense for urls: "i was looking at" http:...
      loading_text: null,                       // [string]   optional loading text, displayed while tweets load
      refresh_interval: null ,                  // [integer]  optional number of seconds after which to reload tweets
      twitter_url: "twitter.com",               // [string]   custom twitter url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      twitter_api_url: "api.twitter.com",       // [string]   custom twitter api url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      twitter_search_url: "search.twitter.com", // [string]   custom twitter search url, if any (apigee, etc.)
      template: "{avatar}{text}{time}",   // [string or function] template used to construct each tweet <li> - see code for available vars
      comparator: function(tweet1, tweet2) {    // [function] comparator used to sort tweets (see Array.sort)
        return tweet2["tweet_time"] - tweet1["tweet_time"];
      },
      filter: function(tweet) {                 // [function] whether or not to include a particular tweet (be sure to also set 'fetch')
        return true;
      }

    }, o);

    // See http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
    var url_regexp = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;

    // Expand values inside simple string templates with {placeholders}
    function t(template, info) {
      if (typeof template === "string") {
        var result = template;
        for(var key in info) {
          var val = info[key];
          result = result.replace(new RegExp('{'+key+'}','g'), val === null ? '' : val);
        }
        return result;
      } else return template(info);
    }

    function replacer (regex, replacement) {
      return function() {
        var returning = [];
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(regex, replacement));
        });
        return $(returning);
      };
    }

    $.fn.extend({
      linkUrl: replacer(url_regexp, function(match) {
        var url = (/^[a-z]+:/i).test(match) ? match : "http://"+match;
        return "<a href=\""+url+"\">"+match+"</a>";
      }),
      linkUser: replacer(/@(\w+)/gi, "@<a href=\"http://"+s.twitter_url+"/$1\">$1</a>"),
      // Support various latin1 (\u00**) and arabic (\u06**) alphanumeric chars
      linkHash: replacer(/(?:^| )[\#]+([\w\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0600-\u06ff]+)/gi,
                         ' <a href="http://'+s.twitter_search_url+'/search?q=&tag=$1&lang=all'+((s.username && s.username.length == 1) ? '&from='+s.username.join("%2BOR%2B") : '')+'">#$1</a>'),
      capAwesome: replacer(/\b(awesome)\b/gi, '<span class="awesome">$1</span>'),
      capEpic: replacer(/\b(epic)\b/gi, '<span class="epic">$1</span>'),
      makeHeart: replacer(/(&lt;)+[3]/gi, "<tt class='heart'>&#x2665;</tt>")
    });

    function parse_date(date_str) {
      // The non-search twitter APIs return inconsistently-formatted dates, which Date.parse
      // cannot handle in IE. We therefore perform the following transformation:
      // "Wed Apr 29 08:53:31 +0000 2009" => "Wed, Apr 29 2009 08:53:31 +0000"
      return Date.parse(date_str.replace(/^([a-z]{3})( [a-z]{3} \d\d?)(.*)( \d{4})$/i, '$1,$2$4$3'));
    }

    function relative_time(date) {
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - date) / 1000, 10);
      var r = '';
      if (delta < 60) {
        r = delta + ' seconds ago';
      } else if(delta < 120) {
        r = 'a minute ago';
      } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 60, 10)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
      } else if(delta < (2*60*60)) {
        r = 'an hour ago';
      } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
        r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600, 10)).toString() + ' hours ago';
      } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
        r = 'a day ago';
      } else {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 86400, 10)).toString() + ' days ago';
      }
      return 'about ' + r;
    }

    function build_auto_join_text(text) {
      if (text.match(/^(@([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)) .*/i)) {
        return s.auto_join_text_reply;
      } else if (text.match(url_regexp)) {
        return s.auto_join_text_url;
      } else if (text.match(/^((\w+ed)|just) .*/im)) {
        return s.auto_join_text_ed;
      } else if (text.match(/^(\w*ing) .*/i)) {
        return s.auto_join_text_ing;
      } else {
        return s.auto_join_text_default;
      }
    }

    function build_api_url() {
      var proto = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:');
      var count = (s.fetch === null) ? s.count : s.fetch;
      if (s.list) {
        return proto+"//"+s.twitter_api_url+"/1/"+s.username[0]+"/lists/"+s.list+"/statuses.json?page="+s.page+"&per_page="+count+"&callback=?";
      } else if (s.favorites) {
        return proto+"//"+s.twitter_api_url+"/favorites/"+s.username[0]+".json?page="+s.page+"&count="+count+"&callback=?";
      } else if (s.query === null && s.username.length == 1) {
        return proto+'//'+s.twitter_api_url+'/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+s.username[0]+'&count='+count+(s.retweets ? '&include_rts=1' : '')+'&page='+s.page+'&callback=?';
      } else {
        var query = (s.query || 'from:'+s.username.join(' OR from:'));
        return proto+'//'+s.twitter_search_url+'/search.json?&q='+encodeURIComponent(query)+'&rpp='+count+'&page='+s.page+'&callback=?';
      }
    }

    // Convert twitter API objects into data available for
    // constructing each tweet <li> using a template
    function extract_template_data(item){
      var o = {};
      o.item = item;
      o.source = item.source;
      o.screen_name = item.from_user || item.user.screen_name;
      o.avatar_size = s.avatar_size;
      o.avatar_url = item.profile_image_url || item.user.profile_image_url;
      o.retweet = typeof(item.retweeted_status) != 'undefined';
      o.tweet_time = parse_date(item.created_at);
      o.join_text = s.join_text == "auto" ? build_auto_join_text(item.text) : s.join_text;
      o.tweet_id = item.id_str;
      o.twitter_base = "http://"+s.twitter_url+"/";
      o.user_url = o.twitter_base+o.screen_name;
      o.tweet_url = o.user_url+"/status/"+o.tweet_id;
      o.reply_url = o.twitter_base+"intent/tweet?in_reply_to="+o.tweet_id;
      o.retweet_url = o.twitter_base+"intent/retweet?tweet_id="+o.tweet_id;
      o.favorite_url = o.twitter_base+"intent/favorite?tweet_id="+o.tweet_id;
      o.retweeted_screen_name = o.retweet && item.retweeted_status.user.screen_name;
      o.tweet_relative_time = relative_time(o.tweet_time);
      o.tweet_raw_text = o.retweet ? ('RT @'+o.retweeted_screen_name+' '+item.retweeted_status.text) : item.text; // avoid '...' in long retweets
      o.tweet_text = $([o.tweet_raw_text]).linkUrl().linkUser().linkHash()[0];
      o.tweet_text_fancy = $([o.tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0];

      // Default spans, and pre-formatted blocks for common layouts
      o.user = t('<a class="tweet_user" href="{user_url}">{screen_name}</a>', o);
      o.join = s.join_text ? t(' <span class="tweet_join">{join_text}</span> ', o) : ' ';
      o.avatar = o.avatar_size ?
        t('<a class="tweet_avatar" href="{user_url}"><img src="{avatar_url}" height="{avatar_size}" width="{avatar_size}" alt="{screen_name}\'s avatar" title="{screen_name}\'s avatar" border="0"/></a>', o) : '';
      o.time = t('<span class="tweet_time"><a href="{tweet_url}" title="view tweet on twitter">{tweet_relative_time}</a></span>', o);
      o.text = t('<span class="tweet_text">{tweet_text_fancy}</span>', o);
      o.reply_action = t('<a class="tweet_action tweet_reply" href="{reply_url}">reply</a>', o);
      o.retweet_action = t('<a class="tweet_action tweet_retweet" href="{retweet_url}">retweet</a>', o);
      o.favorite_action = t('<a class="tweet_action tweet_favorite" href="{favorite_url}">favorite</a>', o);
      return o;
    }

    return this.each(function(i, widget){
      var list = $('<ul class="tweet_list">').appendTo(widget);
      var intro = '<p class="tweet_intro">'+s.intro_text+'</p>';
      var outro = '<p class="tweet_outro">'+s.outro_text+'</p>';
      var loading = $('<p class="loading">'+s.loading_text+'</p>');

      if(s.username && typeof(s.username) == "string"){
        s.username = [s.username];
      }

      if (s.loading_text) $(widget).append(loading);
      $(widget).bind("tweet:load", function(){
        $.getJSON(build_api_url(), function(data){
          if (s.loading_text) loading.remove();
          if (s.intro_text) list.before(intro);
          list.empty();

          var tweets = $.map(data.results || data, extract_template_data);
          tweets = $.grep(tweets, s.filter).sort(s.comparator).slice(0, s.count);
          list.append($.map(tweets, function(o) { return "<li>" + t(s.template, o) + "</li>"; }).join('')).
              children('li:first').addClass('tweet_first').end().
              children('li:odd').addClass('tweet_even').end().
              children('li:even').addClass('tweet_odd');

          if (s.outro_text) list.after(outro);
          $(widget).trigger("loaded").trigger((tweets.length === 0 ? "empty" : "full"));
          if (s.refresh_interval) {
            window.setTimeout(function() { $(widget).trigger("tweet:load"); }, 1000 * s.refresh_interval);
          }
        });
      }).trigger("tweet:load");
    });
  };





})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I know the process of php file, calling it with the parameters (www.XXX.com/updatedb.php?tweet_id=123&tweet_from=123) and so on. just answer me about the JQuery part

Answer (score 2):

See [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - Sending data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Initiate Ajax using jQuery, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'pathTo.php',
    type: POST,
    dataType: JSON,
    data: {
        // This will be a JSON object. So convert your variable 's' into
        // an object and retrieve it from the php file.
    },
    success: function(data_from_php) {
        enter code here after the ajax request has completed successfully
    }
});
```

Comment: do you think that the method called extract_template_data(item) is the best place to write your code ? before the return? or where?

Comment: Another little question, how to retrive a JSon object from php? $_POST['object']=o.item, is that right ?

Comment: All you need to do is within the $.ajax function itself, have a section called success: function(data) { alert(data.object); } This will output the JSON object and on the php end, you need to use a function named json_encode($the_array_in_which_data_is_stored);